# Happy Birthday to us

Tags: discussion, community

We started private beta on 17th June 2014 so Buddhism Stack Exchange (Beta) is now over one year old. The first question to pop onto our newly born site was [Is there an equivalent of heaven and hell in Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1/157) posted at 19.22. I was two days late to the party and my [first post](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/173/157) was on 29th June at 8.25. It was immediately voted down (twice!!!) and I complained about it on my [first meta post](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/157) on the same day.

Downvotes aside, I can't help feeling proud of what we have done. I really believe we have made the internet a slightly better place and added quality questions and answers about the topic we all love - Buddhism. I just wanted to take the opportunity to celebrate Buddhism SE and all who post on here. I wanted to open a thread to see if anyone wants to celebrate a particular aspect, beloved question or personal happening on the site over the last year.

But generally thanks to everyone who has posted here. I've really enjoyed reading all the stuff and I think it's had a positive effect on my Buddhist practice.

Comment: You disapprove of down-voting? Can that feature be disabled for this SE site? At Pets.SE down-votes hardly exist, I suspect people don't want to hurt feelings :-)

Comment: @sss4r Well I think I disapprove of me being downvoted at that point!!! To be fair I don't like excessive downvoting. One downvote of a question if poor is enough to push it to the bottom of a set of answers. Why do more unless it's truly terrible and then it could be a signal for possible deletion. We can't turn downvoting off as that is the SE engine that we work within. To be honest I wouldn't want to - it's needed and I think our site uses it well now. I just don't like to see people pile on and give massive amounts of downvotes. We want to encourage participation not drive people away IMO

Comment: I agree completely. I have to wonder if Facebook is right about not having an unlike button. I don't know how long that will last, given the demand. I think the idea is that the good will rise; what doesn't is naturally down. I think a couple things contribute to down-voting. When a Q or A is already down-voted, I think a person is much more likely to register a down-vote if that is his or her assessment already. And I know badges are supposed to accrue organically, but SE encourages it in its docs (bronze is "easy", silver requires a "strategy") and there's even a dedicated "critical" badge.

Answer (score 4):

I remember I was very happy to find this site. It just occurred to me "what if there is a Buddhism S.E.?" and lo and behold, there it was in area 51. Looking on older posts, I feel sad that a lot of users are not around anymore. But that's how it is...

In any case, I probably visited the site every day during this year. It so happens that it coincided with a period of "buddhism revival" in my life, and I found myself very interested in many questions posted here and in studying answers -- or researching them. This site has been a catalyser to me, even a sangha: the place I found comfortable in, where people are also interested in "better being" -- in this case, the kind promulgated by the Buddha. And there's enough of a culture that protects it from becoming inhospitable. Also, a lot of good people, and a lot of potential to become an important place to clarify Buddhism (this speaks a lot to me, since I come from a country where Buddhism is, generally, not accessible).

Here, I learned about many other resources, experiences, books and points of view that I simply would not be exposed otherwise. Moreover, many questions here reflected doubts I had, but which did not became clear in my head until then. Naturally, I found myself sharing answers I researched to questions I read when realized I really wanted to know it too.

With all that, the community participation, even if virtual, also made a special impression in me. Many of us are very concerned with the eightfold path, like right speech, and seeing this in others, and watching ourselves -- in a Buddhist community, after all -- is quite something to appreciate.

Finally, I see other sites here in S.E. and I really think this could be a really great place. I'm really enjoying participating here with all of you. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Aww...happy first birthday to Buddhism.SE! I've really enjoyed participating here this past year. I've gotten great answers to questions I've asked and had the benefit of learning from others' questions and answers too. My first question was about [Children Monks](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/140/can-someone-explain-about-children-monks) and it felt great to finally have that mystery solved. :)

The information, links to valuable resources, and recommendations have definitely helped to guide my study. Equally or more important has been the feeling of being supported in learning by a caring community and also the pleasure of being able to pass along (hopefully) useful information to others from time to time. A special thank you to our moderators; without you this site would not be the quality resource it is.

Sadhu. _//\_

Comment: Sadhu Robin. I think one of our strong points is that we have a core of maybe 6 - 12 users )maybe more!?!) that care about the site and put in the extra effort contribute to meta, review, edit and all that stuff and that really brings the site to life. And new committed users and coming through all the time. So thank you to you and all the people who hang around on the meta site and really try to point us all the the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been active much, mostly because I just found out of this subpage of stackexchange a couple of days ago. And even though I'm not, currently, practitioning Buddhism, I must say that seeing the questions and answers makes me more relaxed - or zen (although I'm 'afraid' of using that term).

I hope this page will grow, with helpful questions, answers and participants, for I think we need to be more calm, reflective, and responsible for our actions - be it with Buddhism in mind or simply because it's morally the best think to do.

Congratulations with one year being Beta, I'd love it to see it leave the Beta phase and go straight to the real release.

Comment: Thank you and welcome to Buddhism SE. I'm really pleased that you find the site useful. Any suggestions about what we do or how we do it are much appreciated. Ask any on meta if you have any questions and i hope you continue to find it useful. Metta